# CEDET error on every file: Idle Parse Error: "#<buffer XYZ> - Wrong number of arguments

Tags: emacs, cedet

I am trying to use CEDET (checkout from bzr) with emacs 24.2, but every time I try to open a buffer, including my .emacs file, I get the error:

```
Idle Parse Error: "#<buffer .emacs> - Wrong number of arguments: #[(old new when) \"\\303    \\304#\\210\\303\\305#\\210\\303\\306\\307#\\210\\303\\310#\\207\" 
[old new when put overload-obsoleted-by overload-obsoleted-since mode-local-overload t overload-obsolete] 4 (\"/home/sebas/.emacs.d/cedet/lisp/cedet/mode-local.elc\" . 14156)], 2"
```

And if I run semantic-debug-idle-function it returns nothing (or I don't know how to use it). How else could I debug this? The configuration file is practically the same as from Alex Ott, the only "idle" mode in semantic-default-submodes is 'global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode.

I would really like to use CEDET, as I remember it was quite awesome. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some old macros from mode-local lying around. Please make sure that

- you have CEDET properly compiled, that means you did run 'make' and it finished succesfully
- you don't also have CEDET installed through your system's package manager
- you are loading CEDET right at the beginning of your init file

If all of this does not help, please post your problem to the CEDET-devel mailing list, together with the init file you are using.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that an older version, probably bundled with emacs, was being loaded too. I deleted that and the problem is no more.

Comment: Yes, you need to load standalone CEDET first, before any other package

Comment: You don't have to manually delete the version that comes bundled with Emacs. If you load CEDET from bzr early enough, it will remove the bundled version from the load-path.